# EF Core 3.0 preview 7 cannot install for .NET Framework 4.8 project via VS2019 nuget

Tags: .net-framework-version, ef-core-3.0

I have a .NET Framework 4.8 VS2019 solution, that is currently targetting EF Core 2.0.  I attempted to upgrade a project to EF Core 3.0 preview 7 via "Manage Nuget Packages", and get errors like as follows:  Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.0.0-preview7.19362.6 is not compatible with net48 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8) / win. Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.0.0-preview7.19362.6 supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)

I have verified that preview 6 installs OK, which makes sense as that targets .NET Standard 2.0, which is supported by .NET Framework 4.8.

Unfortunately, upgrading my solution file from .NET Framework => .NET Core is not feasible at this time, due to legacy WCF/.NET-remoting which isn't supported in .NET Core (and won't be from my reading).  Likewise, it sounds like .NET Framework will never support .NET Standard 2.1. Does this mean I have to abandon my use of EF Core altogether, if I want to upgrade past .NET Core 3.0 preview 6?

Comment: Unfortunately that's the MS "open source" direction. All the people that for legacy reasons can't switch to .Net Core are just screwed up - no C#8+, no EF Core 3.0+ etc. :-(

Comment: EF Core 3.0 targets .NET Standard 2.1 to enable `async foreach` and nullable reference types. [.NET Framework will never be updated to support .NET Standard 2.1 or higher](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-standard-2-1/)

Comment: Thanks guys for your quick replies.  My solution will be to port to Entity Framework instead, until either WCF is supported by .NET Core, or until my team has time to port WCF => gRpc and upgrade from .NET Framework => .NET Core.

Comment: @bricelam With all my respect, we know that .NET Framework won't be updated. However, the [EF Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/#entity-framework-core) says *"EF Core is a cross-platform product that can run on .NET Core or **.NET Framework**.*". And there is no single word in [Breaking Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes) that you guys are going to target *only* .NET Standard 2.1, thus effectively canceling .NET Framework support. IMHO this should have been in **bold** at the top of the list.

Comment: @Joel As you may imagine from the comments, I and my team are in the similar situation. Luckily not bound to EF (Core), unfortunately heavily bound to WCF. Just FYI, WCF (the server part) *won't* be ported. In fact nothing more from the .NET Framework will be ported after .Net Core 3.0 release.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you for the feedback! I'll get this fixed ASAP

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this article by Microsoft

[.NET implementations supported by EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/platforms/index)

> EF Core 1.x  2.x 3.x
>
> .NET Standard 1.3 2.0 2.1
>
> .NET Core 1.0 2.0 3.0
>
> .NET Framework(1) 4.5.1   4.7.2   (not supported)

and EF core now uses .Net Standard 2.1 as mentioned here
[EF Core 3.0 targets .NET Standard 2.1 rather than .NET Standard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#ef-core-30-targets-net-standard-21-rather-than-net-standard-20)

But when Microsoft announced .Net Standard 2.1 here

[Announcing .NET Standard 2.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-standard-2-1/)
It says that .Net Framework will stay on .net Standard 2

> Given many of the API additions in .NET Standard 2.1 require runtime
> changes in order to be meaningful, .NET Framework 4.8 will remain on
> .NET Standard 2.0 rather than implement .NET Standard 2.1. .NET Core
> 3.0 as well as upcoming versions of Xamarin, Mono, and Unity will be updated to implement .NET Standard 2.1.

Then probably you will never be able to get ef core 3.x on .net framework any more
sorry